# How to clean up registry settings with uninstall?

Tags: excel, installation, uninstallation

I have an installer which needs to add a key to Currentuser under \Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Options.  It must be CurrentUser because excel does not look in LocalMachine.  I have a customer that requires Admin rights for an install.  I found that when the installer was run as the Admin user, the key was created under the Admin users registry settings.  To get around this, I wrote a custom action which created the Excel key in Currentuser, and then copied the key to every other user currently logged on to the machine.  This seems to work.

The problem i now have is on the uninstall.  The registry key is left in place, which causes issues with Excel.  What is the best way to get rid of this registry key on an uninstall?

I am using the Windows installer in VS 2010.

Currie

Answer (score 0):

try installing and running Revo Uninstaller.  Once it's installed, see if excel is still there to be uninstalled.  In REVO, there is a step in the uninstall process where you check the checkboxes, in bold text, of the registry items to be deleted.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/revo-uninstaller/

(on the site, click "download Now" instead of the "download" button at the top (which is just a link to google leads).